# Numpy: Understanding Array to the power of Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I was reviewing operators with numpy arrays and I found something I did not expect and that I do not know how to interpret.

The operation I am performing is an array A to the power of an array B, clearly with A and B having the same shape. The behaviour I am expecting is 'element-wise power': each element of A to the power of the corresponding elements in B. However, it seems that something else is going on.

```
import numpy as np

values = list(range(1, 10))
array_1d = np.array(values)

print(array_1d ** (array_1d * 5))
```

So I'm making `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]` to the power of `[5, 10, 15, 20, ...]`.
The expected outcome (in my head) is the equivalent of `[v ** (v*5) for v in list(range(1,10))]`, that is:

```
 [1,
 1024,
 14348907,
 1099511627776,
 298023223876953125,
 221073919720733357899776,
 378818692265664781682717625943,
 1329227995784915872903807060280344576,
 8727963568087712425891397479476727340041449].
```

However the output is:

```
array([ 1, 1024, 14348907, 0, 167814181, 1073741824, 613813847, 0, -1054898967], dtype=int32)
```

Does someone know the reason of this result? What's really happening here?
Thank you!

Comment: `int32` datatype in `numpy` is in the range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. Numbers larger than that would cause spill-outs. For the largest numbers in `numpy` use `array_1d = np.array(values, dtype=float)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dtype=int32` you're overflowing integers and looping back:

```
1099511627776 % (2**32) == 0
298023223876953125 % (2**32) == 167814181
...
```

Comment: Uhm, interesting. Still, what about 8727963568087712425891397479476727340041449 % (2**32) == -1054898967? That is definitely False!

Comment: No it's not. the type is **signed** int32, so representable numbers go from `-2**31` to `2**31-1`. Depending on how the overflow happens, if the MSB is 1 the number will be interpreted as negative in int32

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the used data type, try:

```
v = arange(1,10, dtype='int32')
print(v ** (5*v))

v = arange(1,10, dtype='int64')
print(v ** (5*v))

v = arange(1,10, dtype='float')
print(v ** (5*v))
```